# Program only rotates square images properly

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, pgm

I have been trying to work with PGM files on C++, getting their negatives etc. 
Now once I started on rotation, I had a rough pseudocode on how we're gonna rotate the matrix, here's the result on a numerical matrix:

[Rotated matrix test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJWwo.png)

On the paper, this seems right. Now when I apply the same algorithm to rotate the images, it only works properly on square image(i.e same height and width):

[Rotated Square Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLr05.png)

But on rectangle images, it produces this kind of result:

[Rotated Rectangle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn0sE.png)

Here's the code:

```
   void loadRotMatrix()
                    {
                        //transpose of matrix
                        for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)
                        {
                            for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
                            {
                                rotatedmatrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
                            }
                        }
                        //flipped transposed
                        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
                        {
                            int temp =0;
                            for(int j=0,k=cols-1;j<k;j++,k--)
                            {
                            temp=rotatedmatrix[j][i];
                            rotatedmatrix[j][i]=rotatedmatrix[k][i];
                            rotatedmatrix[k][i]=temp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Now I cannot for the life of my decode what's going on here and what is turning my dog into a cerberus :p

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the array (width and height) are different when the image is not rectangular.

You will need to rotate the arrayinto a different array for the indices to make sense.

```
int sourceMatrix[100][200];

int destMatrix[200][100];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot flip nor transpose non-square matrix. Before doing math, add extra rows or columns to make a matrix square, do the math, then strip the added columns or rows back to get the original image without the padding.

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to picture being cut off? I cannot process how'd you fill the matrix up then

Comment: if rows > columns (add extra colums), if rows < columns (add extra rows), then after processing you have to strip extra rows in the first case and extra columns in the second (your image got rotated, remember?).

Comment: if It's not too much trouble, could you please visualize what you're trying to say? I am quite new to matrix manipulation :)